# Where is the best place to find loads of dervish slimes?

Tags: slime-rancher

I am prepping and planning on turning Mochi's Manor and Viktor's laboratory into havens for dervish slimes. I am in the end game now, and I wanted to make as many newbucks as I possibly can, just for fun.

I am willing to wait at one spot, but statistically where would be the best place to find Dervish slimes in bulk? I do not think it matters, but I am playing on PS4 on the latest version (1.4.4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can only be found in the "The Glass Desert" or through "Gordo Snares".  Keep in mind that they spawn in Oases when they are restored.

Comment: I understand that they only spawn in the glass desert, but is there a specific area in the glass desert that has a consistent spawn point and has lots of them spawning?

Comment: As far as I know, only in restored Oases. But they are not consistent either. I would try the Gordo Snares. They provide a large quantity of them after feeding them to max.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Slime Rancher wiki](https://slimerancher.fandom.com/wiki/Dervish_Slime):

> They [dervish slimes] are found exclusively in The Glass Desert.